# How to create dataframe subset of the one patient observation with the lowest score on a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data-management, subset

Hello I have a dataset with multiple patients, each with multiple observations.
I want to select the earliest observation for each patient.

```
Example: 

Patient ID    Tender    Swollen    pt_visit
101             1         10          6
101             6         12          12
101             4         3           18
102             9         5           18
102             3         6           24
103             5         2           12
103             2         1           18
103             8         0           24
```

The pt_visit variable is the number of months the patient was in the study at the time of the observation.  What I need is the first observation from each patient based on the lowest number of months in the pt_visit column.  However I need the earliest observation for each patient ID.

My desired results:

```
Patient ID    Tender    Swollen    pt_visit
101             1         10          6
102             9         5           18
103             5         2           12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, use the `ddply` function in the `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)
firstObs <- ddply(df, "PatientID", function(x) x[x$pt_visit == min(x$pt_visit), ])
```

Comment: Also `function(x) x[which.min(x$pt_visit)]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the data.table package:

```
Data <- data.table(Data)
setkey(Data, Patient_ID, pt_visit)
Data[,.SD[1], by=Patient_ID]
```

Comment: Either solution works fine. From my standpoint, data.table is unnecessary for a beginning user unless they're working with huge datasets (they'll need to learn data frames regardless, and it could be confusing to learn data frames and data tables simultaneously).

Comment: Heh, the same could be said about using plyr.

Comment: I find `data.table` pretty useful on small data sets too. It's really more about which one you're more used to in my opinion.

Comment: The dataset is large, about 6000 observations. I used a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Patient ID` column is actually named `Patient_ID`, here are a few approaches.  `DF` is assumed to be the name of the input data frame:

**sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select Patient_ID, Tender, Swollen, min(pt_visit) pt_visit 
   from DF 
   group by Patient_ID")
```

or

```
sqldf("select *, min(pt_visit) pt_visit from DF group by Patient_ID")[-ncol(DF)]
```

*Note:* The above two alternatives use an extension to SQL only found in SQLite so be sure you are using the SQLite backend.  (SQLite is the default backend for `sqldf` unless RH2, RProgreSQL or RMYSQL is loaded.)

**subset/ave**

```
subset(DF, ave(pt_visit, Patient_ID, FUN = rank) == 1)
```

*Note:* This makes use of the fact that there are no duplicate `pt_visit` values within the same `Patient_ID`.  If there were we would need to specify the `ties=` argument to `rank`.

Comment: What about postgresql package ?

Comment: yes, sqldf has support for the postgreSQL back end if you load the  RPostgreSQL package prior to issuing the sqldf command; however, its pretty easy to use the default SQLite here so unless you are using postgreSQL anyways I think most people would use SQLite here.

Comment: Thanq Mr.Grothendieck.

Answer (score 0):

I almost think they should be a `subset` parameter named "by" that would do the same as it does in `data.table`. This is a base-solution:

```
do.call(rbind,  lapply( split(dfr, dfr$PatientID), 
                  function(x) x[which.min(x$pt_visit),] ) )

    PatientID Tender Swollen pt_visit
101       101      1      10        6
102       102      9       5       18
103       103      5       2       12
```

I guess you can see why @hadley built 'plyr'.